# Sending content of a file in Expect

Tags: linux, unix, expect

How Can I send the content of a file in Expect? Do I have to use cat command in a way? if yes how? lets say my file is called 1.txt.

example:

expect "Enter command to send:" {send "???? \r"}
???? --> content of the file 1.txt.

Comment: do you want to *send* the file or *receive* it?

Answer (score 4):

expect is just a tcl script app so you can do anything you can do in tcl, such as

send [cat 1.txt]

you can also open the file and read and write its content with tcl.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with expect version 5.45 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. I get `invalid command name "cat"`.

Comment: You can use instead: send [exec cat 1.txt]